# OAuth JWT Bearer Flow and Managed Packages

Tags: managed-package, oauth2, jwt

Does anyone know if the Certificate uploaded to a Connected App in my Dev org will be installed automatically to all customers through a Managed Package?

Right now I have a small analytics app that I use with a couple of clients. For each client I manually setup a Connected App and copy the Consumer Key & Secret to use for the integration. I'm looking to scale to more customers in the future and want to distribute the Connected App through a Managed Package (and eventually put it on AppXChange). The JWT Bearer flow looks ideal (as I sync new data nightly), but it won't work unless I can also get the certificate included... otherwise I'd have to get each client to manually upload the certificate which won't be scalable.

Answer (score 1):

The `digital certificate` that goes with the connected app is not auto-installed along with the connected app. There is an open idea for this on [ideaExchange](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000Gdc5gUAB/package-certificate).

You might have to manually upload them or have a script to update it.